# Using gulp.src as a writable passthrough?

Tags: node.js, gulp

As per the [changelog](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#380) and lots of other stuff ([1](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/396), [2](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/548), [3](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl-fs/issues/25)), I'm under the impression I should be able to do this:

```
gulp.task('js', function(){
    gulp.src('js/*')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.src([
            'lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            'lib/canjs/can.jquery.min.js',
            'lib/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.js',
            'lib/momentjs/min/moment.min.js'
        ]))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
});
```

Trying to first pull my code, minify, add lib files, concat all, and write. I don't want to be uglify-ing all these lib files that have already been minified.

I think I'm up to date.

```
$ gulp -v
[15:11:30] CLI version 3.8.0
[15:11:30] Local version 3.8.6
```

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: What happens if you replace `gulp.src('js/*')` with `gulp.src('js/**/*')`?

Answer (score 1):

That first github issue you posted shows that it's not fixed yet.  I think your best bet for now is to try out the [gulp-add-src](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-add-src) workaround @contra described.

Comment: I guess the developers of gulp-add-src plugin were also under impression that it now works and deprecated their plugin too early.